# How to add chromedriver to path when there isn't anything like chromedriver?

Tags: drivers, python, google-chrome, selenium

I am trying to automate some stuff using selenium.

I use Chrome for some reason but I can't instantiate Chrome that I am using normally. I used webdriver_manager, but it install Chrome again in another directory.

To instantiate Chrome without these problems, I need to find chromedriver file (and pass the directory of the file to the python script), but this file doesn't seem to exist anywhere. I installed chrome by [www.google.com/chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) ,it gave me a deb file and I opened it with "Software Install".

How can I find the chromedriver file?

Answer (score 0):

I found it under
'/opt/google/chrome/chrome'
And I ran the command like:
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/opt/google/chrome/chrome')
And it worked.

How did I manage?(For it to work for you too):
I searched for chrome under directories, and then in '/usr' directory, I found the applications, and the Chrome. Right-click, properties, I found it was a shortcut from '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'. I went there. Right-click-> properties, it is a shortcut, which is in '/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome' directory.